# Почему элементы в Relative Layout никак не хотят ставиться по центру горизонтально?

Tags: android, xml

Проблема заключается в том, что элементы в Relative Layout никак не хотят ставиться по центру горизонтально, даже если свойство layout center horizontal = true, Relative Layout вложен в Scroll View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы прогресс бар расположился по центру надо установить у `RelativeLayout` ширину `match_parent`

Вот работающий лейаут:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Что-то как-то не поменялось ничего. В визуальном xml-редакторе оно так в углу и осталось, а в самом приложении вообще пустота.

Comment: @ArEfremov я сам лично проверил в студии. все работает прогресс по центру